# ImageView doesn't appear

Tags: android

I have dragged an `ImageView` to layout and I selected the picture. But when I execute the application, It doesn't appear. What can I do to solve this ?

[image]

ImageView XML code;

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/idlepoor_moneys"
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: **android:src** Sets a drawable as the content of your ImageView , **app:srcCompat** is for integrating vector drawables into your app .. Vector drawables allow you to replace multiple png assets with a single vector graphic, defined in XML .if you use that you need to add.... **vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true** to your build.gradle file.. So depend on your requirement pick the right one.. If you only need to Sets a drawable as the content  use **android:src**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this property in Your image View

```
android:src="@mipmap/idlepoor_moneys"
```

Remove the following line from your code

```
app:srcCompat="@mipmap/idlepoor_moneys"
```

Answer (score 1):

As allready said change

```
app:srcCompat="@mipmap/idlepoor_moneys"
```

to

```
android:src="@mipmap/idlepoor_moneys"
```

Also I recommend to put your images in the @drawable folder. The mipmap is where app icons are stored when making an app.

```
app:src="@drawable/idlepoor_moneys"
```

You can easily find the drawable from your project map. If you can't find it you can always right click the folder to get the path to it.